# Calculating a compass angle?

Tags: sensor, electromagnetism, compass

I am getting data from compass( `hmC5883L`)  and trying to detect angle.

Well, i dont really care about offsets, i just want to check that if its flat on the table and i make a 90 degrees round, i will get numbers `x-> 90+x`

Instead **for 90 degrees turn** i get values like that :
(starting from 13 degrees)

```
13->180, jump right to 0, 0->180, 180->13
```

code to manipulate data :

```
                float gScale = .92;  // Scale factor for +1.3Ga setting

                float adjx = x - xOffset; //set to 0 for testing
                float adjy = y - yOffset;//set to 0 for testing

                xs = adjx * gScale; 
                ys = adjy * gScale;
                zs = z * gScale;    

                float heading = atan2(ys, xs);
                heading += declination / 1000; // Declination for geo area

                   if (heading < 0);
                     heading += 2*PI;

                   if (heading > 2*PI)
                     heading -= 2*PI;

                  float angle = heading * 180/M_PI;
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: you have to remember that the compass is possibly drifting constantly, and you haven't shown us where you get the data in - which could be wrong too

Comment: thanks, what do you mean where did i get the data in ? i am using Wire library with arduino and read the data as usual, i think the technical details are not relevant because i do get everything to work, only calculate wrong. if you look at it, it seems that my angles are going 0-180 always, and not 0-360, although i do zeroing it every 2pai

Comment: Look for atan2() it gives [-pi,pi]

Comment: `PI` and `M_PI`  why are you using both?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič he is using Atan2

Comment: @KyranF I see that is using atan2, but the result isn't in range [0,2pi] as is he doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            float gScale = .92;  // Scale factor for +1.3Ga setting

            float adjx = x - xOffset; //set to 0 for testing
            float adjy = y - yOffset;//set to 0 for testing

            xs = adjx * gScale; 
            ys = adjy * gScale;
            zs = z * gScale;    

            float heading = atan2(ys, xs);
           if (heading < 0)
            heading += 2*PI; // translate result atan2() from [-PI,PI] to [0, 2*PI]  

            heading += declination / 1000; // Declination for geo area
            if (heading < 0) heading += 2*PI;;

            if (heading > 2*PI) heading -= 2*PI;

            float angle = heading * 180/PI;
```

Comment: Unless you actually need the magnetic field strength in mG, you can omit `gScale` and the multiplication.  Mathematically, the heading will be the same.